# Unable to use two variables on same blade file, probable routing issue

Tags: laravel

I'm developing a web site that has a page to display affirmations. On this web page, I have added a save to favourites button using which user can save any affirmation to their id.

Next, I'm looking to display their saved affirmations on the same web page. But I'm facing some issue which feels like a routing issue. Here are my relevant codes:

Web.Php file:

```php
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/affirmations', [AffirmationsController::class, 'index'])->name('affirmations');
    Route::post('/upload-image', [AffirmationsController::class, 'uploadImage'])->name('upload.image');
    Route::post('/save-favorite/{affirmationId}', [AffirmationsController::class, 'saveFavoriteAffirmation'])->name('save.favorite.affirmation');
    Route::get('/saved-affirmations', [AffirmationsController::class, 'savedAffirmations'])->name('saved.affirmations');
});
```

AffirmationsController.php file:

```php
public function index()
{
    $affirmations = Affirmation::all();

    return view('affirmations', ['affirmations' => $affirmations]);
}

public function savedAffirmations()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $savedAffirmations = $user->favoriteAffirmations;

    return view('affirmations', ['savedAffirmations' => $savedAffirmations]);
}
```

Affirmations.Blade.Php file:

```xml
<div id="carouselExample" class="carousel slide">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    @foreach($affirmations as $index => $affirmation)
      <div class="carousel-item {{ $index == 0 ? 'active' : ''}}" data-affirmation-id="{{ $affirmation->id }}">
        @if($affirmation -> image_path)
          <img class="d-block w-100" src = "{{ asset('storage/' . $affirmation -> image_path)}}" height="500px" alt="Affirmation Image">
        @else
          <img class="d-block w-100" src = "{{ asset('storage/hero.jpg')}}" height="500px" alt="Default Image">
        @endif
      </div>
    @endforeach
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <h2> Your Saved Affirmations </h2>
    @if($savedAffirmations->count() > 0)
      @foreach($savedAffirmations as $savedAffirmation)
        <p>Affirmation: {{ $savedAffirmation->text }} (ID: {{ $savedAffirmation->id }})</p>
      @endforeach
    @else
      <p>You don't have any saved affirmations yet.</p>
    @endif
  </div>
```

What I've observed is that currently, with the routing configurations given above, the `$savedAffirmations` function is not being called at all and hence I am getting the `Undefined variable $savedAffirmations` error. However, if I change the route to

```
Route::get('/affirmations', [AffirmationsController::class, 'savedAffirmations'])->name('saved.affirmations');
```

and use a `dd($savedAffirmations)` in the `$savedAffirmations` function, I can see that the variable does have the information needed. In this case, however, once I remove the dd statement, I start getting an `Undefined variable $affirmations` error.

I've been stuck on this for days. Please advise on steps I can take to get this working. Please let me know if there's any other piece of code that you need to check to be able to make suggestions. I'll be extremely grateful for your help!

Thank You!

Comment: You're using the same view for two different functions. That would be fine, except you're passing in two very different variable names into the view, and expecting both to exist. Pass both variable names into the view in both functions with null values or empty collections. Since you're calling `$savedAffirmations->count()` on the view, that will need to be an empty collection.